# How to quickly access files in different folders in emacs?

Tags: emacs

Basically I have different type of files in different folders. org notes in E:\org-notes , certain php files in e:...\wamp\www\  and so on. And I want to quickly open files from these different folders. Whats a good way here? to jump between folders.

I thought having recentf would solve the problem, but it still involved too much typing. Something like recentfolders would do the job.

Also I don't want to have desktop-save-mode on , as I think it causes problems with having multiple windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine recent files with a package which allows you to type any part of the filename. [Here are some packages for opening files from the history](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RecentFiles). I recommend Anything, but the others are also good.